# swfobject event listeners not working?

Tags: event-handling, youtube-api, swfobject

I have essentially taken the code from the youtube api tutorial, starting the video playback immediately, and invoking a callback for state changes. Playing is working, so I know the `onYouTubePlayerReady` function is firing, and the ytplayer object is defined. However, the event listener is not working.

Here is the callback function for when the youtube player is loaded:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
  ytplayer.playVideo();
}
```

And here is the event listener:

```
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
 alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
```

I hate when no one answers and I google it later, only to find out my stack overflow question is one of the top results.

Comment: This is really weird, it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the YT API reference:

> Note: To test any of these calls, you must have your file running on a webserver, as the Flash player restricts calls between local files and the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "myytplayer" where did you define that . I had the same problem , it was due to the wrong reference of an Id . check that again.